# Strange (memory?) issue with std::vector.push_back()

Tags: c++, memory, vector, cout, push-back

I have a function `getfafr(N,n,twoq)` that returns a 3-dimensional tensor `fafr` in the form of `std::vector<vector<vector> > >`. It does not have uniform size (i.e. `fafr[i][j].size()` can be different for different `i,j` etc), which is implemented using `push_back()`.

The strange thing is that running the function with the exact same parameters can result in different tensors; sometimes at least some of the elements are gibberish. One example is running `getfafr(12,3,1)` at different points in the code at one time gave `fafr[2][0][10]=270` and at another gave `fafr[2][0][10]=-6.88461e-309`.

The strange thing is that if I always print the tensor to screen after creation using `std::cout` the issue disappears.

My feeling is that using `push_back()` in this way can result in memory problems, like earlier data being overwritten by later or something. Here is the function:

```
vector<vector<vector<double> > > getfafr(int N, int n, int twoq) {

    vector<vector<vector<double> > > fafr;

    for(int nu=0;nu<n;nu++) {

        fafr.push_back(vector<vector<double> >(twoq+nu+1));

        for(int om=0;om<=twoq+nu;om++) {

            for(int tmo=0;tmo<N-nu-twoq;tmo++) {

                fafr[nu][om].push_back(bin(twoq+nu, om));

                for(int i=N-tmo-nu-twoq;i<=N-1-tmo-om;i++) fafr[nu][om][tmo]*=i;

                for(int i=tmo+1;i<=tmo+om;i++) fafr[nu][om][tmo]*=i;
            }
        }
    }

    return fafr;
}
```

Comment: Switch from using `operator[]` to using `at` and I have a feeling the problem will become obvious.

Comment: Hm, not for me.. It didn't give `'std::out_of_range'` error if that's what you mean?

Comment: What does `bin()` return?

Comment: Sorry, `bin` is the binomial coefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    auto x = getfafr(12, 3, 1);
    cout << x.size() << ' ' << x[2].size() << ' ' << x[2][0].size() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3 4 9
```

So you go out of bounds when you try to access `fafr[2][0][10]`. Changing it to `fafr.at(2).at(0).at(10)` (as suggested in the comments) could help you.

Comment: Well, it's not gonna solve the problem, but it will certainly make it more obvious.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was actually in another function that checked differences between 'old' and 'new' `fafr`; it didn't take into consideration the 'non-square' property of `fafr`.